# ios9 Safari and jquery mobile scrolling error

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios9

I have a jquery mobile (v1.2) page which is online since 3 years. Everything works fine, except in iOS 9 Safari, I have a problem with scrolling of pages.

I don't know, how to explain the problem exactly, but if you post a form, the result page appears, but you can't scroll down, and only a white space is rendered. Have a look at the screenshot.

[image]

If you reload the page, everything is fine again and you can scroll down.
If you want to see/test it yourself: http://urlgone.com/f0a05f/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
[data-role="page"] {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

This should resolve your issues. Newer iOS Safari scrolling can be difficult to work with.

Comment: This fixes my scrolling issues, but causes drawing issues, changing focus and updating the DOM makes the page go blank for me. Is anybody else experiencing this?

Comment: Not allowed to edit my comment? Anyway, to clarify, when I tap an input field the page turns solid white and only when I enter the first character in the input field does it redraw and make all elements visible again

Comment: Fixed that issue. Was a combination of various CSS selectors (-webkit-backface-visibility, transform, perspective) being on 2 divs which were nested, removing it from the container solved all sorts of issues for me.

Comment: So do you think my original answer would still solve the issue for the majority of users? Or should we incorporate your fix as well?